# Physical Checks - Mailing

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, check, personal-check

I am about to mail a check directly to a financial institution in the USA where the receiver holds an account, so that the money from the check can be deposited into the receiver's account. However, on the check, neither on front nor on back side, are any bank account details (routing number, account number, bank name) saying on which exact account should be money deposited. On the front side there is only the full name of receiver and thats all.

How do I tell inside the letter (i repeat: inside the letter and not personally or verbally on the phone) other info of receiver such as address on account, account number, routing number.

I have never mailed a check before. Is there any official and original form where can I type this (either with hand or with keyboard on computer)? Is there an exact layout of the document where with exact elements of document to be filled how must the form (the document) look like?

To clarify: I am talking about the form/documents on which I define where the money from check should be deposited? Full name on front side of check is for sure not enough. Or can I use 100% random white paper? There might be something more officially required.

Comment: Until you explain why you are mailing it to the bank, I don't think you will get good answers. In North America it is very unusual to send a cheque to someone's bank for deposit. You send the check to the person or company, and they deposit it, taking care of these issues like "What account" and so on. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: Most banks will only accept checks given to them by the person receiving the money, the recipient will have to fill out paperwork specific to that bank and only available to customers of that bank to deposit it. There is no way to deposit a check into another persons account in any country I know of, they must do it. (unless you are a close family member like the recipients spouse, depositing it on their behalf)

Comment: @Vality In the UK pretty much anyone can deposit a check/cheque into someone else's account if they have the recipient's bank details. So long as the payee, and the destination account match, the banks mostly don't care who hands them over the counter (although it's probably easier, and/or less likely to attract a fee, if you do it either at a branch of the recipient's bank, or your own).

Answer (score 6):

Lets say you owed me $123.00 an wanted to mail me a check. I would then take the check from my mailbox an either take it to my bank, or scan it and deposit it via their electronic interface.

Prior to you mailing it you would have no idea which bank I would use, or what my account number is. In fact I could have multiple bank accounts, so I could decide which one to deposit it into depending on what I wanted to do with the money, or which bank paid the most interest, or by coin flip.

Now once the check is deposited my bank would then "stamp" the check with their name, their routing number, the date, an my account number. Eventually an image of the canceled check would then end up back at your bank. Which they would either send to you, or make available to you via their banking website.

You don't mail it to my bank. You mail it to my home, or my business, or wherever I tell you to mail it. Some business give you the address of another location, where either a 3rd party processes all their checks, or a central location  where all the money for multiple branches are processed.

If you do owe a company they will generally ask that in the memo section in the lower left corner that you include your customer number. This is to make sure that if they have multiple Juans the money is accounted correctly.

In all my dealings will paying bills and mailing checks I have never been asked to send a check directly to the bank. If they want you to do exactly as you describe, they should provide you with a form or other instructions.

Comment: mhoran_psprep: Thank you for your reply but you overlooked the most important information. I am mailing it directly to financial institution and they will deposit the money from check (no max limit) on wanted receiver's bank account. So the receiver doesn't need to use the check on his/her or, if business account (or personal joint) their own. Receiver told me she prefers to NOT get the check to her hands and want me to do what I already said. At the bottom on the front page of check there is MY account and routing number from source of money so from my account (i am payer). You completely mis

Comment: Juan - why is the normal process not good for the recipient? Can't she accept your check and go to her bank with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing on the back of the check, in the signature area, "For deposit only to account xxxxxxxxx", leaving room for the signature. This may or may not be legally binding, but it states your intnt and is in a form the bank will recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a personal check does not detail the account number that the funds will be deposited to, only the name of the individual/company. It's the recipient's role to deposit the funds into whatever account they choose.

You could specify the routing number and account number on the memo line, but there's no guarantee that the bank will read this information. Based on your description, it sounds like you need to do a wire transaction. This is a transaction performed between banks (yours and theirs). You call your bank and tell them you want to do a wire, and provide the recipient's details, including their bank routing and account numbers.  The wire is usually completed the same day.

**Note that many scams involve wire transfers, and they can rarely be stopped or reversed. understand the risks and use due diligence, especially when dealing with international wires**

Good luck.

Comment: This is 100% incorrect.  Typically personal checks include the account number.

Comment: I've never seen a check that included the recipient's account number, only the writer's.